# Rust invoking callback inconsistent number of times

Tags: rust, iterator

I ran into this issue when trying to write an example for my wrapper crate. Skip to the heading **The problem** to get straight to the issue

### The example

The function of note here is `vmaf.get_vmaf_scores` which will accept an optional callback function (for the purposes of providing progress updates. In this case, a CLI progress bar). This code is largely insignificant, but I'm including it here to show how my example is set up

```rs
use indicatif::{ProgressBar, ProgressStyle};
use libvmaf_rs::{
    model::{config::ModelConfig, Model},
    video::Video,
    vmaf::{status::VmafStatus, Vmaf},
};

fn main() {
    let vmaf = Vmaf::default();

    let reference: Video = Video::new(&"./video/Big Buck Bunny 720P.m4v", 1280, 720).unwrap();
    let distorted: Video = Video::new(&"./video/Big Buck Bunny 720P.m4v", 1280, 720).unwrap();

    let num_frames = reference.len();

    let model_config = ModelConfig::default();
    let model = Model::new(model_config, String::from("vmaf_v0.6.1")).unwrap();

// Create progress bars
    let style =
        ProgressStyle::with_template("{prefix}: {eta_precise} {wide_bar} [{pos}/{len}]").unwrap();

    let decode_progress = ProgressBar::new(num_frames.try_into().unwrap())
        .with_prefix("Calculating Vmaf Scores")
        .with_style(style.clone());

    let get_score_progress = ProgressBar::new(num_frames.try_into().unwrap())
        .with_prefix("Getting scores")
        .with_style(style);

// in each status variant, increment each respective progress bar
    let callback = |status: VmafStatus| match status {
        VmafStatus::Decode => decode_progress.inc(1),
        VmafStatus::GetScore => get_score_progress.inc(1),
    };

    let scores = vmaf
        .get_vmaf_scores(reference, distorted, model, Some(callback))
        .unwrap();

    decode_progress.finish();
    get_score_progress.finish();

    let average: f64 = scores.into_iter().sum::<f64>() / num_frames as f64;

    println!("Pooled VMAF Score: {average}");
}
```

### The symptom

Which, when run yields the following console output

```
Calculating Vmaf Scores: 00:00:00 █████████████████████████░ [1798/1800]
Getting scores: 00:00:00 ███████████████████████████████████ [1800/1800]
Pooled VMAF Score: 98.6341010333127
```

This is unexpected. because of the nature of how I wrote `get_vmaf_scores` I would expect  that both progress bars would be 1798 (that `reference.len()` gave me an inaccurate count)

### The problem

I know the code below looks a bit complicated, but I'd like to provide a guide on what's going on here. We have two iterators (which know exactly how many items they contain) which implement `TryInto` for Picture. These iterators are `zip`-ed into an iterator of tuples `(reference,distorted)`

- In the first `map` closure (**see Exhibit A comment**), I am converting from `AVFrame` (from the *ffmpeg-next* crate) into `Picture` using try_from. This will either yield an `OK(tuple of Pictures)` or `Err(PictureError)`
- These are then further processed down the iterator pipeline until being collected into a `Vec<Result<usize,VmafError>>` (**See Exhibit B comment**). Please note that I do not filter this iterator at any step, and that as per **Exhibit A**, I invoke the callback regardless if `try_into` succeeded or not for either frame. That is to say **The first callback is called unconditionally for every item in this iterator**
- Finally, at **Exhibit C** I iterate through every framepair and for each `OK` value in the sequence, I call the callback function with `VmafStatus::GetScore` and then actually get the score

  - If I get a single `Err` variant in this sequence, I immediately early return from `get_vmaf_scores` with an `Err` using the `bail!` macro from error_stack

#### To recap:

I take two iterators of Frames, unconditionally invoke the callback function for each item then collect into a vector of indexes. (then I do some prepatory work before I can actually start getting scores). From this vector of indexex (wrapped in results) I call the callback function again for every `OK` variant and early return otherwise.

Given that there is no filtering in the first iterator pipeline, I would expect that the number of times the callback function was called with `VmafStatus::Decode` and `VmafStatus::GetScore` to match

```rs
pub fn get_vmaf_scores<
        I: GetResolution
            + ExactSizeIterator
            + Iterator<Item = impl TryInto<Picture, Error = Report<PictureError>>>,
        F: Fn(VmafStatus) -> (),
    >(
        mut self,
        reference: I,
        distorted: I,
        model: Model,
        callback: Option<F>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<f64>, VmafError> {
        // Use features from model
        self.use_features_from_model(&model)
            .change_context(VmafError::Feature(model.version()))?;

        // Ensure videos have the same number of frames
        let ref_frames = reference.len();
        let dist_frames = distorted.len();

        if ref_frames != dist_frames {
            return Err(Report::new(VmafError::FrameCount(ref_frames, dist_frames)));
        }

        // Ensure videos have same resolution
        let ref_resolution = reference.get_resolution();
        let dist_resolution = distorted.get_resolution();

        if ref_resolution != dist_resolution {
            return Err(Report::new(VmafError::Resolution(
                ref_resolution.clone(),
                dist_resolution.clone(),
            )));
        }

        let framepair = reference
            .zip(distorted)
            .map(
// Exhibit A
                |(reference, distorted)| -> Result<(Picture, Picture), PictureError> {
                    let reference_pic = TryInto::<Picture>::try_into(reference);
                    let distorted_pic = TryInto::<Picture>::try_into(distorted);

                    // Call callback with VmafStatus::Decode for every frame pair
                    if let Some(callback) = &callback {
                        callback(VmafStatus::Decode)
                    }

                    match (reference_pic, distorted_pic) {
                        (Ok(reference), Ok(distorted)) => Ok((reference, distorted)),
                        (Ok(_), Err(distortederr)) => Err(distortederr),
                        (Err(referenceerr), Ok(_)) => Err(referenceerr),
                        (Err(referr), Err(_)) => Err(referr),
                    }
                },
            )
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(index, result)| match result {
                Ok((reference, distorted)) => {
                    match self.read_pictures(reference, distorted, index.try_into().unwrap()) {
                        Ok(()) => Ok(index),
                        Err(e) => Err(e).change_context(VmafError::Other),
                    }
                }
                Err(error) => Err(error.change_context(VmafError::Other)),
            })
// Exhibit B
            .collect::<Vec<Result<usize, VmafError>>>();

        // Do some cleanup before retrieving scores
        // This is by necessity due to underlying FFI library
        self.finish_reading_pictures()
            .change_context(VmafError::ClearFrame)?;

        let mut scores: Vec<f64> = vec![];

// Exhibit C
        for pairindex in framepair {
            match pairindex {
                Ok(index) => {
                    // Call callback with VmafStatus::GetScore for every score we retrieve from self
                    if let Some(callback) = &callback {
                        callback(VmafStatus::GetScore)
                    }
                    
                    let score = self
                        .get_score_at_index(&model, index.try_into().unwrap())
                        .change_context(VmafError::GetScore(index.try_into().unwrap()))?;
                    scores.push(score);
                }
                Err(e) => bail!(e),
            }
        }

        Ok(scores)
    }
}
```